# Azure Table Storage - Why are my bool and string properties being stored, but my int and double properties are not?

Tags: c#, azure

This sounds like it should be a simple issue, but I am having difficulty singling it out.

I have a `TableEntity` class that I am trying to write to `Azure Table Storage`:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
  public MyEntity(string imageId, string featureId)
  {
    this.PartitionKey = imageId;
    this.RowKey = featureId;
  }

  public string Container { get; set; }
  public bool FeatureEnabled { get; set; }
  public int data;
  public PointF Point;
  public double X;
  public double Y;

}
```

I understand that my `Point` property will not be saved to Table Storage. But when I insert this entity, the `Container` property and `FeatureEnabled` both get stored, but nothing else?

How can this be? `int` and `double` are said to be supported, so what could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Container` and `FeatureEnabled` are Properties of the class. The others are simply Fields. `TableEntity` will only search for and automatically save Properties (of the supported types).

So make data, x, and y into properties by providing `get; set;` in the same way as the ones that do work.

Comment: Ah! That makes so much sense! Thanks! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define getter/setter for your int/double properties:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
  public MyEntity(string imageId, string featureId)
  {
    this.PartitionKey = imageId;
    this.RowKey = featureId;
  }

  public string Container { get; set; }
  public bool FeatureEnabled { get; set; }
  public int data { get; set; }
  public PointF Point;
  public double X { get; set; }
  public double Y { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TableEntity is very limited in terms of the types of properties it supports.

If you use ObjectFlattenerRecomposer API that I implemented
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

You can get all your properties including the Point property, written to table Storage, the api also handles recomposing the original object back when you read the entity back from table storage.

Here is a usage example:

```
using ObjectFlattenerRecomposer;

//Flatten object and convert it to EntityProperty Dictionary

Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> flattenedProperties = EntityPropertyConverter.Flatten(complexObject);

// Create a DynamicTableEntity and set its PK and RK

DynamicTableEntity dynamicTableEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);

dynamicTableEntity.Properties = flattenedProperties;

// Write the DynamicTableEntity to Azure Table Storage using client SDK

//Read the entity back from AzureTableStorage as DynamicTableEntity using the same PK and RK

DynamicTableEntity entity = [Read from Azure using the PK and RK];

//Convert the DynamicTableEntity back to original complex object.

Imagine original complexObject was of type Order.

Order order = EntityPropertyConverter.ConvertBack<Order>(entity.Properties);
```